# Kafka Structure streaming java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /10.233.8.214:50723 error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to run basic kafka structure streaming word count program. This program is working in my personal machine, But in my client Virtual machine, it is failling. I am trying to run this program in local mode.

Error:

> java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /10.233.8.214:51300
>           at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:232)
>           at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:182)
>           at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.downloadClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:366)
>           at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.openChannel(NettyRpcEnv.scala:332)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:654)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:480)
>           at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:696)

Spark code I am running:

```
spark = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName("StructuredKafkaWordCount")\
        .getOrCreate()

    # Create DataSet representing the stream of input lines from kafka
    lines = spark\
        .readStream\
        .format("kafka")\
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers)\
        .option(subscribeType, topics)\
        .load()\
        .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")

    words = lines.select(
        # explode turns each item in an array into a separate row
        explode(
            split(lines.value, ' ')
        ).alias('word')
    )

    # Generate running word count
    wordCounts = words.groupBy('word').count()
    # Start running the query that prints the running counts to the console
    query = wordCounts\
        .writeStream\
        .outputMode('complete')\
        .format('console')\
        .start()

    query.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with Structured Streaming in particular but Apache Spark itself. Can you execute the streaming query as a batch one and see if it works? I don't think so. Try something like `Seq("hello world").toDF("line").select...explode...split...groupBy...count...show`.

Comment: You are correct. It has nothing to do with streaming, if I add external packages/jars for simple spark program I am getting this error. What can be the reason for it?

Comment: Looks like the Virtual machine is misconfigured. What's the IP 10.233.8.214? Could you ping it? Looks like networking issue.

Comment: Yes that is my IP. I pinged it. It gave response.

Comment: Thank you, @JacekLaskowski, My company firewall blocked spark session. My network team solved by unblocking it

Comment: Glad to hear so! Can you then answer your question and approve? That'd help others to find the solution.